# Scala return type for tuple-functions

Tags: function, scala, types, return, tuples

I want to make a scala function which returns a scala tuple.

I can do a function like this:

```
def foo = (1,"hello","world")
```

and this will work fine, but now I want to tell the compiler what I expect to be returned from the function instead of using the built in type inference (after all, I have no idea what a `(1,"hello","world")` is).

Comment: OK, folks...I blame the compiler for not giving me any useful information. I forgot to put the = sign, hence I got tons of errors.

If anyone comes with an elaborate answer I will accept it though, the correct way was:

def foo:Tuple[Int,String,String] = (1,"hello","world")

Comment: Tuple3[...]

even, remember to put the# of items in the class name (max 22ish)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
def foo : (Int, String, String) = (1, "Hello", "World")
```

The compiler will interpret the type `(Int, String, String)` as a `Tuple3[Int, String, String]`

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can create a type alias if you get tired of writing (Int,String,String)

```
type HelloWorld = (Int,String,String)
...

def foo : HelloWorld = (1, "Hello", "World")
/// and even this is you want to make it more OOish
def bar : HelloWorld = HelloWorld(1, "Hello", "World")
```